# Visual Studio breakpoints being moved

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, breakpoints

I originally used Visual Studio C++ Express, i've switched to ultimate and im currently confused as to why the debugger is moving my breakpoints, for example:

```
if(x > y) {
    int z = x/y;         < --- breakpoint set here
}
int h = x+y;             < --- breakpoint is moved here during run time
```

or

```
random line of code      < --- breakpoint set here
random line of code

return someValue;        < --- breakpoint is moved here during run time
```

It seems to do this at random locations in the code. Is there sometime i'm doing wrong here? I've never had an issue with the express version like this happening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are debugging in release mode.

```
if(x > y) {
    //this statement does nothing
    //z is a local variable that's never used
    //no executable code is generated for this line
    int z = x/y;         < --- breakpoint set here
}
//the breakpoint is set on the next executable line
//which happens to be this one
int h = x+y;             < --- breakpoint is moved here during run time
```

Usually debuggers set hooks inside binary code. If no binary code is executed for `int z = x/y`, you can't set a breakpoint there.

The following is generated by compiling this in release mode:

```
if(x > y) 
{
    int z = x/y;//         < --- breakpoint set here
}
int h = x+y;
cout << h;
003B1000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (3B203Ch)] 
003B1006  push        7    
003B1008  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (3B2038h)]
```

To test this, you can perform this simple change:

```
if(x > y) {
    int z = x/y;
    std::cout << z << endl; // <-- set breakpoint here, this should work
}
int h = x+y;
```

Comment: I agree this is the most likly cause, I would also note that in the past I have seen disconects between the lines reported via the debugger and the IDE due to line termination diffrences (NL vs CR NL) I recall this bing a big issue in the Borland Delphi products, but I do not think this is an issue wth VS.

Comment: @tletnes hmm interesting, I've never encountered this though in VS.

Comment: Right on! I completely overlooked that I was in release mode. Thank you!

Comment: That's true. VC6 used to show a message box if breakpoints are disabled or moved ahead. None of VC versions show message box but disable/move the BP.