# C++/CLI seems to skip a line of code and debugging does not show the variable declared and defined in that line

Tags: debugging, c++-cli, clr

I have only been developing in C++/CLI and C++ for a few months now but it seems to me that the programming language should not matter regarding this issue.

In the following lines of code, `double k = (yEnd - yStart) / (xEnd - xStart);` appears to be not executed.

```
//double k = 1.0;
if (xEnd - xStart == 0)
{
    selected = true;
    return true;
}

// Checks if Y-coordinate corresponds to X-coordinate
else 
{
    // Calculating the slope of the line
    double k = (yEnd - yStart) / (xEnd - xStart);

    if (fabs(y - (yStart + k * (x - xStart))) < (double)selectionTolerance)
    {
        selected = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have tried to debug it line by line with F11 and have also set breakpoints, though these breakpoints move when running the debugger from the said line to `if (fabs(y - (yStart + k * (x - xStart))) < (double)selectionTolerance)` after it.

I have checked in the options of Visual Studio not to skip properties/operations, but it also didn't help. When the debugger halts the program at the if, I can not see any value of `k`, but can see all the other ones without problems (with the exception of char selectionTolerance and bool selected, all of them are double as well).

Thank you for the help, I have searched the web and stackoverflow for a long time but could not find a problem with a line as simple (and probably general) as this.

### Update:

Thanks to David Yaw and G K, I was able to see the value of k. I am still puzzled by an issue illustrated here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDwXm.png (cannot yet post images)

Even though `yEnd`, `yStart`, `xEnd`, `xStart` are all of type `double` and have the values as seen in the image above, when the program halts at line 254 before executing `k=ydif/xdif;`, `k` equals `0.0000000000000000`. I added the three lines

> double ydif= (yEnd-YStart);
>   double xdif=xEnd-xStart;
>   k=ydif/xdif;

to see the if `k` would be calculated as wanted, but it got the same value after pressing F11 again (program halts at line 256).

I found a question which is related to the jumping breakpoint issue here: [Visual Studio breakpoints being moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384371/visual-studio-breakpoints-being-moved)

What is the problem with calculating `k` the way I try it, and what would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Is optimization enabled or disabled?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thank you for the hint! It is now disabled - I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention that the calculation was incorrect, just that the line of code wasn't getting hit. I'm assuming the calculation is correct.

The local variable was likely optimized out by the compiler. Since you only used `k` in one spot, it eliminated the local variable, and did the slope calculation inline, in the `if` statement.

I've seen the C++/CLI compiler do similar things with method calls: I've gotten exceptions where the stack trace lists a method I don't call: The method I call was inlined, and the stack trace pointed to the method that it called.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, sorry for the late response, was not able to test it till today (also researched the topics you mentioned in your answer). Part of the problem remains with 'k' being calculated unlike I would expect.

Comment: 'k' seems to be calculated inline in more than one spot.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Visual Studio 10.0 C++ compiler. The debug configuration uses the following command line switches when debugging  /Gm /Od /RTCs /Zi /LDd Sorry I do not remember what each does. You can run the compiler in CLI and get a listing of what all the command line switches do. Those basicly turn of all optimizations.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I learned something about the work of compilers! I found this relating to what you wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4707425/2250207 - I can see values now. I can't yet up-vote answers, but I will once I am allowed to.